# How to grep two terms at the same time in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as follows

```
chr     Type
1     Tum,B,B,Tum
2     B,B
3     Tum,Tum
4     B,B,B,Tum
```

I would like to only select those rows which have BOTH Tum and B to be inserted into a new dataframe with the following result:

```
chr     Type
    1     Tum,B,B,Tum
    4     B,B,B,Tum
```

I have tried the following

```
PusungMix <- as.data.frame(Pusung[grep("Barr"&"Tum", Pusung$Type])
```

but I get the error

```
Error in "Barr" & "Tum" : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use a double `grepl` to create the two logical index and check whether for instances where both are TRUE using `&`.  This can be used for subsetting the rows of 'df1'.

```
 indx <- grepl('B', df1$Type) & grepl('Tum', df1$Type)
 df1[indx,]
 #  chr        Type
 #1   1 Tum,B,B,Tum
 #4   4   B,B,B,Tum
```

Or as @Gaurav suggested in the comments, `subset` is another option if we don't want to use `[`.   We can remove the `df1$` within the `subset` and also don't have to worry about dropping the dimensions as `drop=FALSE` is the default in `subset`, whereas in `[`, it is `drop=TRUE`.  So, when we have a single column or single row, it will drop the dimensions to a `vector` if we don't specify explicitly `drop=FALSE` in `[`.

```
 subset(df,grepl('B', Type) & grepl('Tum', Type))
```

Comment: `subset(df,grepl('B', df1$Type) & grepl('Tum', df1$Type))` will work too

Answer (score 2):

Or by pure `regex` w/o the need of 2 `grepl`:

```
indx <- grepl("Tum.*B|B.*Tum", df1$Type)
df1[indx, ]

#   chr        Type
# 1   1 Tum,B,B,Tum
# 4   4   B,B,B,Tum
```